Fantasy short story where an artist sees in an oneiric vision a woman who has died years earlier
I read this fantasy short story in a collection, in French, only 5 or 6 years ago, but "before Covid". I think, however, that it is much older.
It takes place, I believe, about 150 or 200 years ago. (That does not necessarily mean it was written at that time, but maybe it was). Indeed, in the mansion in the countryside, where it takes place, they still use candles for light. The point-of-view character (POV) is an artist, a painter, and he and a few more artists have been invited for a few days by their friend, a French aristocrat, owner of that mansion. This feels like France around the XIX° century rather than much earlier.
So these artists arrive together at the mansion, and in the evening each retires to his assigned room. The walls of the POV's room are covered with portraits of his host's ancestors. The POV immediately falls asleep, but wakes up to a fantastic scene: all his host's ancestors come out of the frames of their portraits and walk into his room. Or rather, dance. IIRC, to music made by musicians in some of the paintings on the wall.
Only one young woman has no dancing partner. So the POV invites her to dance. She agrees and they dance all night till daybreak. Then something terrible happens, I forgot exactly what. The POV is so disturbed by this horror that he faints.
When he wakes up, late morning, his host and his artists friends tell him that they had found him unconscious on the floor, and they had to put him in his bed some hours before.
Some time later, he takes paper and pencil and starts drawing the face of the woman of his nightmare/vision.
His host remarks that this face looks very much like his sister's. The artists asks him to be introduced to her, but the host informs him she had died a few years before. The artist is devastated at this news.

La Cafetière (The Coffee Pot,  1831), the first short story by Théophile Gautier.
From this review:

“The Coffee Pot” is best described as an extremely brief vignette stylistically similar to the sort of thing Poe or Lovecraft were wont to produce, if wholly without their macabre bearing.  An unnamed narrator joins two friends in accepting an invitation to a weekend at an isolated estate somewhere in Normandy (read as “way out in the country”). Arriving through a torrential storm, they pull themselves together sufficient to have dinner and subsequently retire to their rooms.
Unable to sleep, the narrator awakens to see a coffee pot dancing its way over towards the fireplace, and stoking its embers through unseen means.  A man steps out of a portrait, and producing a key, unlocks the other portraits in the room, releasing a succession of musicians, huntsmen and dancers.
A beautiful woman catches our hero’s attention, and he pays her court. She is advised against consorting with him, but chooses to pay no heed, and they dance divinely to the applause of those assembled, then snuggle and coo through the course of the evening.  With first light, she raises herself up with a start, only to collapse before the fireplace.  Our narrator goes to help her up, but only finds the coffee pot, shattered to bits.  He faints.
Next morning, he is awakened by his friends, who find him back in bed, but dressed in their host’s grandfather’s wedding suit.  Apparently they had discovered him lying on the ground, clutching a piece of the pot “as if it were some pretty girl”.  Later at breakfast, he doodles a portrait of the girl absentmindedly, and is told the picture looks astonishingly like their host’s sister Angela, who had died 6 months agone, “after catching pneumonia at a ball”.  The narrator ends the tale with a grand proclamation that “I then realized there was no happiness left in the world for me at all”.

As far as I can see, the English version of the story is not available on archive.org or the Gutenberg Project, but can be read in  this Google Books preview of The Oxford Book of French Short Stories, or read aloud by this guy on YouTube:




Found with the Google query nouvelle fantastique invite artiste fantômes sortent cadre dansent (fantasy short story invited artist ghosts come out frames dance) which brought up the story as contained in a French PDF  ebook.

Exactly my story. I had just forgotten about the coffee pot and the artist clutching a piece of it.
